How to authenticate an Android app user using a cached Okta access token?
I'm new to Okta and trying to understand it's Identity Engine library.  The scenario I want to achieve is this:

User logins in once on the first app start
Next app start we check the cached users credentials to see if their valid, and the user doesn't need to login each time.  It invalid we use a refresh token to update the access token

How can I accomplish this?  The only Okta sample app (okta-idx-android) does not show how to cache the credentials and instead requires the user to login each time.  The library does provide a Credentials wrapper class that does seem to handle caching the token, but if I call any it's functions like credential.introspectToken(TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN) or getValidAccessToken() and the access token is not valid I have no way to restart the InteractionFlow because any attempt to do so gives me an exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: cookieJar was already accessed, and can't be set."  What am I doing wrong?  What's another way I can restart the InteractionCodeflow without using the class?
